# chrome.proxy API for Firefox WebExtensions

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-developer-tools

Does Firefox WebExtensions support an API to change proxy preferences (like the [chrome.proxy API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy))?

Does Mozilla have plans to add it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Starting from 55th Firefox it will be possible.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/proxy

Keep in mind, this API absolutely different from Chrome version.

For code split use `typeof browser === 'undefined'`

Answer (score 4):

### Firefox 60+

As of Firefox 60, Firefox and Firefox for Android support the [proxy API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/proxy), which is available through `browser.proxy`. It is roughly similar to the [`chrome.proxy` API on Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy).

### Firefox 56-71

There was what should now be considered a false-start of Firefox supporting a different semantic for setting the proxy using `browser.proxy.register()` and `browser.proxy.unregister()`. They were first introduced in Firefox 56, depricated in Firefox 68 and will be removed after either Firefox 70 or 71 (depending on which documentation is to be believed).

### Earlier versions of Firefox

WebExtensions does not yet support the `chrome.proxy` API. There are plans to support it in the future (as there are [plans for basically all of the Chrome extension APIs](http://arewewebextensionsyet.com/)).

There are two related tracking bugs:

- [Bug 1295807 - [tracking] Support proxy configuration from WebExtensions](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1295807)
- [Bug 1283639 - [tracking] Proxy API support for WebExtensions](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1283639)

There is a thread about "[WebExtension Proxy API Design](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/dev-addons/2016-July/001678.html)" on the [Dev-addons mailing list](https://mail.mozilla.org/listinfo/dev-addons).

For now, If you want to manipulate proxy settings from a Firefox add-on, you will need to use some [other type of add-on](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910014948/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/getting-started-with-firefox-addon/13574/introduction#t=201709100149489262324).